# How to find a specific html element with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I have this element in html :

```
<input data-v-72dea36a="" type="text" name="tradelink" placeholder="Enter your code" style="margin-right: 25px;">
```

How can I select exactly this one? I tried:

```
find_element_by_name('tradelink')
```

There is another element before this one with the same name...it doesn't have an id or class name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are just 2 elements with attribute `name="tradelink"`, and assuming you need the seconds one, you can use:

```
find_elements_by_name('tradelink')[1]
```

Another way is using `xpath` to match the `placeholder` value:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter your code']")
```

Notes:

- Notice the plural on element**S** on the 1st example
- Selenium Docs - [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)
- Fore more than 2 elements, you may have to change the array item number, i.e.: `find_elements_by_name('tradelink')[2]`

Comment: thanks, i used xpath and got the path with the chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick the element within the inspect element editor and select copy full xpath. As posted above, paste that code into the parentheses in `find_element_by_xpath()`